# Can a checkbox only be checked after a user clicks a hyperlink (Terms and Conditions?)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp-classic

I am trying to write a form where users select an option, and certain forms show as a result of that option--I have that working great with jquery. Next, I am trying to make the user have to click the hyperlink to the Terms and Conditions before they can check a checkbox.

I have seen multiple examples of how users must click the checkbox in order to see the hyperlink, but I am wondering if it can go the other way around.

```html
<div id="additionalForm" class="FormDiv">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Housing Agreement</legend>
    <input id="chkSignature" name="chkSignature" type="checkbox" required>
    <label for="chkSignature">
       <b>I have read and I agree to the 
   <a href="TermsandConditions.asp" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>
       </b>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Right now, I have validation for the checkboxes, but no way for me to see if they are actually reading the content within the hyperlink. I'd like to make the user click the hyperlink in my HTML before they can check the box.

Comment: So disable the checkbox, and add a click event listener to the link.  When it's clicked, remove the disabled attribute from the checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Added the `disabled` attribute on the checkbox
- Added a click event listener to the click of the link
- Removed the disabled attribute when the link is clicked

```js
document.querySelector('#termsAndConditions')
  .addEventListener('click', function(e){
    document.querySelector('#chkSignature').removeAttribute('disabled');
  });
```

```html
<div id="additionalForm" class="FormDiv">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Housing Agreement</legend>
    <input id="chkSignature" name="chkSignature" type="checkbox" required disabled>

    <label><b>I have read and I agree to the <a href="TermsandConditions.asp" target="_blank" id="termsAndConditions">Terms and Conditions</a></b></label>

  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic! I simply was not aware of this functionality as I am new to the scene. That being said, users can still submit through the HTML even without checking #chkSignature because the form is disabled until the link has been clicked. Therefore the form is no longer required. I have made back end validation for this form so they cannot submit the form, but for the sake of consistency is there a way to have the checkbox required yet disabled?

Comment: Requiring something that the user cannot interact with doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Well the checkbox is only visible when a certain variable from my select list is selected. So i think it does make sense to make this checkbox required no matter what, and only clickable after a user has read the terms. Regardless, I truly appreciate your prompt responses and I think I have enough thanks to you.

Comment: Keep in mind, there is a difference between "disabled" and "hidden".  A hidden input will still be sent on a form submit.  A disabled one will not.  So depending on what you want, those are two different tools you have in your developer tool belt.